# mysql trigger after insert not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

I tried from several examples and could not reach my goal - so I am asking here...

I have a table :
table1
columns : col1 , col2

I want to change col2 after an insert :
If (col2 = 0) then 
   alter col2 to be max(col2) + 1
else
   leave the value as it is
Thanks

Comment: what is the last thing you tried? CREATE TRIGGER trg_name AFTER INSERT  ON your_table BEGIN <more code here> END; this work? this gives an error? what error?

Comment: my first error was that I used "after insert"
second error is I used the wrong column in the table (...$#@#*#(@) :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it using before insert since before insert you can check if the `col2` is `0` and then set the value to `max col2 + 1`

Here is a way to do it

```
delimiter //
create trigger test_ins before insert on table1
for each row 
begin
  declare max_col2 int;
  if new.col2 = 0 then
    set max_col2 = (select max(col2) from table1);
  end if ;
  if max_col2 is null then
    set new.col2 = 1 ;
  else 
    set new.col2 = max_col2 + 1 ;
  end if ;
end ;//
delimiter ;
```

Note that in the above trigger I have added a check such that if the `max(col2)` is null which will happen when you add the first record in the table and `col2` as 0 I am setting it as `1`

```
if max_col2 is null then
        set new.col2 = 1 ;
```

You can set it as you want.

Here is a test case

```
mysql> create table table1 (col1 int, col2 int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.13 sec)

mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create trigger test_ins before insert on table1
    -> for each row 
    -> begin
    ->   declare max_col2 int;
    ->   if new.col2 = 0 then
    ->     set max_col2 = (select max(col2) from table1);
    ->   end if ;
    ->   if max_col2 is null then
    ->     set new.col2 = 1 ;
    ->   else 
    ->     set new.col2 = max_col2 + 1 ;
    ->   end if ;
    -> end ;//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.10 sec)


mysql> delimiter ;

mysql> insert into table1 values (1,0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from table1;
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into table1 values (2,0);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> select * from table1;
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    2 |
+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Again - thanks for your reply.

However, I tested it and it seems :

1. Not to add + 1 to the next value (and I really do not know why it is like that).
2. Leave the value if it is defined (I wrote above: "else leave the value as it is")

I changed your code a bit and put some extra IFs.
Now it is working OK (for me).

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trigCF7Submits 
BEFORE INSERT ON wp_cf7dbplugin_submits

FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  DECLARE nMaxInternalNumber INT;

   IF ((new.form_name='ActionForm') AND (new.field_name='txtActionFormInternalNumber')) then
      IF (new.field_value = 0) THEN
         SET nMaxInternalNumber = (SELECT max(field_value) FROM wp_cf7dbplugin_submits WHERE ((form_name='ActionForm') AND (field_name='txtActionFormInternalNumber')));         

         IF (nMaxInternalNumber IS NULL) THEN
            SET nMaxInternalNumber = 0;
         END IF;

         SET nMaxInternalNumber = nMaxInternalNumber + 1;
      ELSE
         SET nMaxInternalNumber = new.field_value;
      END IF;

      SET new.field_value = nMaxInternalNumber ;
    END IF ;
END ;//
DELIMITER ;
```